# Is there a way for webpack to know if a global is not declared?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm using some externals (google's js being one), and I have `'use strict'` statement at the top of the file. I know I can fake imports with webpack's resolve config parameter, but that only allows me to import modules that aren't a part of the source.

I'd like a global that wasn't "imported" or like, would throw an error when webpack processes.

As an example:

```
var foo = bar
```

I'd expect bar (not declared or imported) would be an error with `'use strict'`.

I'm using webpack 1.13.1

Comment: You can try ESLint with no-undef rule: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

Comment: It's easy to achieve with ESLint what you ask but without `'use strict'` condition (you can't specify ESLint rule depend on is `'use strict'` given or not).

Comment: Perfect. I was using eslint already but for some reason never thought to check for an eslint rule.

Comment: Do you want to answer with configs of `webpack.config.js` and `.eslintrc`?

Comment: I don't have an opinion. I don't know if there's a best practice, or standard. I just added the rule to my package.json eslintConfig and all is good. Fill out a sane recommendation for the answer and it's yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent building packages with undefined variables with help of [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) and [`no-undef rule`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef).

Prepare packages for this solution

```
npm install eslint eslint-loader eslint-friendly-formatter --save-dev
```

You should configure `.eslintrc`

```js
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-undef": 2 // <-- ERROR on not defined variables
    }
}
```

In your `webpack.config.js` you must add this lines to support linting with ESLint

```js
module.exports = {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        },
        // ...
    ],
    eslint: {
        failOnError: true, // block build on non passed linting
        configFile: '.eslintrc', // path to your .eslintrc
        formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter') // better error report
    },
    // ...
};
```

This configs gives you this kind of error

```
ERROR in ./src/example.js
Module build failed: Error: Module failed because of a eslint error.

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef  'bar' is not defined
  /yourpath/src/example.js:2:11
  var foo = bar;
             ^


✘ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```